# How to count both null values as well as distinct values of non-null columns in a table

Tags: null, amazon-redshift, distinct-values

I have what I think should be a simple query but it may not be after all. I need to do two things in a single query (preferably):

1. Count the #of recs (in multiple columns) where the value is NULL
2. Count the #of distinct recs on a particular column

Basically the table is a list of claims data and is organised in the following way...

1. A claim number can occur multiple times. I would like to count distinct claim numbers (this field will never be NULL)
2. NULL values can occur in one or more columns

Sample Data:

```
insert into t1 (ID, LOB, Funding, Claim_ID, Claim_Type, Pharmacy_ID)
values (3617623, 'DRUG', NULL, 2389753478, 'ORG', 'OA734'),
(3462090, 'DRUG', NULL, 2389753478, 'REV', 'OA734'), 
(3587262, NULL, NULL, 5356201834, 'ORG', NULL), 
(3160932, 'DRUG', NULL, 4627282840, 'ORG', NULL), 
(3986523, 'DRUG', NULL, 4627282840, 'REV', NULL), 
(3874627, 'DRUG', NULL, 7735624780, 'ORG', '43857')
```

Expected result:

1. Count of total records = 6
2. Count of Claim_ID = 4
3. Count of NULL LOB = 1
4. Count of NULL Funding = 4
5. Count of NULL Claim_Type = 0
6. Count of NULL Pharmacy_ID = 2

I tried with this query but it doesn't quite work:

```
select
sum (case when LOB is null then 1 else 0 end) as LOB_null,
sum (case when Funding is null then 1 else 0 end) as Funding_null,
sum (case when Claim_Type is null then 1 else 0 end) as Claim_Type_null,
sum (case when Pharmacy_ID is null then 1 else 0 end) as Pharmacy_ID_null,
sum (count (distinct (case when claim_id is not null then 1 end)) as ttl_claims,
sum (case when ID is not null then 1 end) as ttl_recs
from t1
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to count distinct `claim_id` for rows that satisfy the specified conditions instead of counting records:

```
select
sum (case when ID is not null then 1 end) as ttl_recs,
count (distinct case when claim_id is not null then claim_id end) as ttl_claims,
count (distinct case when LOB is null then claim_id end) as LOB_null,
count (distinct case when Funding is null then claim_id end) as Funding_null,
count (distinct case when Claim_Type is null then claim_id end) as Claim_Type_null,
count (distinct case when Pharmacy_ID is null then claim_id end) as Pharmacy_ID_null
from t1
```

and if there's any change the same `claim_id` can have 2 rows with NULL attribute in one row and NOT NULL in another you have to group by `claim_id` first to resolve conflicts like you want and then produce the summary of that aggregate

Comment: THNXS so so much @AlexYes for your answer! Your modification of my attempt at solving my problem works!I think I will need however to find a way to make the solution more efficient. As it stands right now, it takes 4m and 58s to run against 26,957,022 records

Comment: @Gar is your table sorted/distributed by `claim_id`?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. The table is in Amazon's Redshift and I'm still learning my way around that database's particularities.  But to answer your question, I'm not exactly sure. I'd like to think that the ID and Claim_ID columns are keys in the table but I just tried running a pg_table_def command and got nothing back

Comment: better recreate the table with `SORTKEY (claim_id)` at the end, insert data and run `VACUUM` and `ANALYZE`, and then check how the query works. Sortkey will ensure rows with the same `claim_id` are together on the disk so the count is more efficient

Comment: makes sense; I'll raise it with our dba and see what he says